# How to resolve a Future inside another Future

Tags: scala

I want to create a function similar to the following. Basically the function, say `F` will create a `Future` say `fut1`. When `fut1` resolves, then another `Future` say `fut2` should get created inside `fut1`. The `fut2` should return the final value of the function `F`. The code has to be non-blocking all the way. I have written something like this but the return type is not `Future[Int]` but `Future[Future[Int]]`. I understand why this is the case (because `map` creates a `Future`) but I am unable to figure out how to return `Future[Int]` from this code.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def fut:Future[Int] = {

  val f1 = Future{ 1 } //create a Future
   f1.map (x => {  //when f1 finishes, create another future
    println(x)
    val f2 = Future{ 2 }
     f2.map(x=> x)  //this creates another Future and thus the return is Future[Future[Int]]
    }) 
 }
```

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/concurrent/Future.html#flatMap[S](f:T=>scala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]

Comment: You must resolve one of the futures. In the body of the `map()`  but probably your code won't wait, as there is not instruction for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using flat map or for comprehension.

**FlatMap**-

```
def futureFunctionWithFlatMap: Future[Int] = {

val f1 = Future {
  1
}
f1.flatMap(x => {
  println(x)
  val f2 = Future {
    2
  }
  f2.map(x => x)
})
}
```

**For Comprehension**

```
def futureFunctionWithForComprehension: Future[Int] = {
for {
  f1 <- Future {    1     }
  f2 <- {
    println(f1)
    Future { 2  }
  }
} yield f2
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap`

```
val f1 = Future{ 1 } //create a Future
val f2: Future[Int] = f1.flatMap(x => {
  //will be triggered only after x is ready
  Future{2}
})
```